# Is it safe to change the android:name attribute value in the <application> element?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm well aware that we should not change the name of application components in an app's manifest (as described [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)). But what about changing the value of the `android:name` attribute in an app's `<application>` tag? This attribute should point to a subclass of `Application`. Is it safe to change the manifest to point to a different class? (I want different `Application` subclasses for different flavors of my app.)

Comment: I feel this is a loaded question?  Of course you can use different Application subclasses in build variants.  Possible issue could come with google services - If you use a different `applicationIdSuffix` with each flavour and a `google-services.json` file you will need one per flavour, (same level as the `AndroidManifest.xml` in each flavour) so adding each flaour namespace as an App in the firebase project in the firebase console.

Comment: @MarkKeen - Loaded question? Why would you would suspect that? This has nothing to do with Google services or Firebase. The situation is that I am working with a published app. To meet changing app requirements, future versions of the app may need to have distinct `Application` subclasses for different app flavors. I was simply asking if changing the `android:name` attribute of the `<application>` tag would break anything. (I'm asking because other names cannot be changed. Changing the name of an exported activity can break home screen shortcuts after an update, for instance.)

Comment: The core purpose of build variants is to have different variations of your app - what you want to do is what it is designed for.  As for nothing to do with Firebase, sure I said it was a "possible" issue, since any firebase services are initialised in the App class, the very class you want to subtype, I thought it was worth a side mention.  The fact your app is already published does give some insight/more context into your question - nobody wants side effects to a already published app.

Comment: @MarkKeen - Fair enough. I thought that describing the problem as one of changing the name implied that it was already published; otherwise it would just be setting the name. But I should have been clearer about the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this only affects the inside of the app when Android starts it up and is safe to change between flavors or versions of the app. The Android framework uses it to configure the creation of the application object, but it won't have any external effect or persist between executions of the app. An already installed app therefore shouldn't run into any problems being updated or similar.

It's not something that I have used extensively, so testing is always recommended. However, based on my experience as a software architect and working with the Android platform, I would consider this very low risk. I can't see any potential for bad interactions with Android or other apps outside of the app itself (since the application object can only be accessed inside the app).